# Cannot click on disabled button in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to **click** on a disabled button ('*delete*') and verify its warning toaster popup ("*cannot delete this item*"). The **click** doesn't happen with `element(by.name('view')).click();` maybe coz its a **disabled button**, idk.

Following is the **Error** that I get : `jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the webdriver control flow.`

The button element looks like the following:

```
<input name="view" type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-primary disabled " ng-click="vm.edit(1)" value="Edit" />
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: That's because it disabled. Why is it disabled if you are gonna click on it?

Comment: @Dvir - I know its a very small test but It has a toaster pop up when clicked .. that I want to test  "you cannot delete this item"

Comment: It's kind of safety if the user removed the disabled from the button? I think your question not so clear

Comment: It has the "disabled" class, but not the "disabled" attribute, right?

Comment: @alecxe : yes, you are right!

Comment: Could you show the complete code you have so far? Also, are you sure there are no other elements with `name="view"`?

Comment: `
it('should delete an item', function () {
    var popUp = new Toaster(); //page object
    element(by.name('view')).click().then(function(){
 popUp.closePopup("Item could not be removed."); //some method in page object
    });
});
`

No, there are no other elements with name = "view";

Comment: I apologize , i'm not able to format the code properly. Newbie here!

Comment: @CodeRJ whenever you try to click on an element, protractor makes sure that its `enabled` and `displayed` on the screen to perform the operation. Your error shows that element is not clickable(enabled and displayed) and so the spec is timing out waiting for the element to be clickable. Can you check if your element is both [enabled](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isEnabled) and [displayed](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed) and see if its returning true? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the element is enabled and displayed!